# Problem with Ok/Cancel buttons not showing second time in UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app and on one machine (Windows 10 current) the buttons show the first time the dialog box is invoked, but second and subsequent times the buttons do not show up. It only happens on this one machine so I believe it to be machine specific but no errors are thrown and I can't find any hints on how to diagnose this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could create a new project on this machine to test whether this error also occurs.
In addition, could you please provide detailed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue, had a field that spanned a single line and forced the display on the dialog box down one line. On that one computer, this caused the OK/Cancel buttons to be "below" the bottom of the dialog. I could not reproduce on any other computers so think it may be a display driver issue, but I fixed the overflow and that cleared up my problem. Sorry for the dump question.